# Why cant javax.websocket not be resolved?

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket

why cant my import be resolved?

I got a JDK project, converted it to maven and added all the required dependencies into the POM file.
Yet it still is not able to import the websocket files.

Whats my mistake?

[image]

[image]

Some more screenshots of the project setup:

[image]

And here my POM file:

[image]

I tried the Fix project setup, but also didnt really help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your project and run Maven->Update Project...

If it is not working, go to your Maven's local repository, delete javax.websocket and try Update Project... again

Comment: Thank you i tried that but it didnt help. Update didnt help, and delete+update didnt help either. I added some more pictures to show the setup but i really dont know whats wrong there